# Data filter for required area in GEE?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I would like to create a LST map of Chakwal district Pakistan. I need  a data filter for my required area (Chakwal district) because in the 'USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017' product only exists Pakistan border. What product can be used instead?

```
var dataset = ee.FeatureCollection('USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017');
var PakistanBorder = dataset.filter(ee.Filter.eq('country_na', 'Pakistan'));
print(PakistanBorder);
Map.centerObject(PakistanBorder, 6);
Map.addLayer(PakistanBorder);
var modis = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/MOD11A2');
var start = ee.Date('2012-01-01');
var dateRange = ee.DateRange(start, start.advance(1, 'year'));
var mod11a2 = modis.filterDate(dateRange);
var modLSTday = mod11a2.select('LST_Day_1km');
var modLSTc = modLSTday.map(function(img) {
  return img
    .multiply(0.02)
    .subtract(273.15)
    .copyProperties(img, ['system:time_start']);
});
var ts1 = ui.Chart.image.series({
  imageCollection: modLSTc,
  region: PakistanBorder,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  scale: 1000,
  xProperty: 'system:time_start'})
  .setOptions({
     title: 'LST 2012 Time Series',
     vAxis: {title: 'LST Celsius'}});
print(ts1);
var clippedLSTc = modLSTc.mean().clip(PakistanBorder)
Map.addLayer(clippedLSTc, {
  min: 17, max: 40,
  palette: ['blue', 'limegreen', 'yellow', 'darkorange', 'red']},
  'Mean temperature, 2012');
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: clippedLSTc,
  description: 'LST_Celsius_ug',
  folder: 'my_folder',
  region:PakistanBorder,
  scale: 1000,
  crs: 'EPSG:4326',
  maxPixels: 1e10});
  var image = ee.Image('users/ejaza977/shapefile');
```

Answer (score 0):

Chakwal district is located in the Dhanni Region of the Potohar in northern Punjab. So, you only need one point to locate it among the 51 districts of Punjab province; as it can be observed in following lines by using 'FAO/GAUL/2015/level2' product instead 'USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017'.

```
var dataset = ee.FeatureCollection('FAO/GAUL/2015/level2');
var PakistanBorder = dataset.filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM0_NAME', 'Pakistan'));

//print(PakistanBorder);

var punjab = dataset.filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM1_NAME', 'Punjab'));

print(punjab);

var chakwal_pt = ee.Geometry.Point([72.8533, 32.9248]);

var chakwal = ee.Feature(punjab.toList(punjab.size()).map(function (ele){
  
  return ee.Algorithms.If(ee.Feature(ele).intersects(chakwal_pt), ele, 0);
  
}).removeAll([0]).get(0)).geometry();
```

With this in mind, your code can be rewritten as follows:

```
var dataset = ee.FeatureCollection('FAO/GAUL/2015/level2');
var PakistanBorder = dataset.filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM0_NAME', 'Pakistan'));

//print(PakistanBorder);

var punjab = dataset.filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM1_NAME', 'Punjab'));

print(punjab);

var chakwal_pt = ee.Geometry.Point([72.8533, 32.9248]);

var chakwal = ee.Feature(punjab.toList(punjab.size()).map(function (ele){
  
  return ee.Algorithms.If(ee.Feature(ele).intersects(chakwal_pt), ele, 0);
  
}).removeAll([0]).get(0)).geometry();

Map.addLayer(chakwal, {}, 'chakwal district');
Map.centerObject(chakwal);
Map.addLayer(chakwal_pt, {}, 'chakwal point');

var modis = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/MOD11A2');

var start = ee.Date('2012-01-01');
var dateRange = ee.DateRange(start, start.advance(1, 'year'));
var mod11a2 = modis.filterDate(dateRange);
var modLSTday = mod11a2.select('LST_Day_1km');

var modLSTc = modLSTday.map(function(img) {
  return img
    .multiply(0.02)
    .subtract(273.15)
    .copyProperties(img, ['system:time_start']);
});

var ts1 = ui.Chart.image.series({
  imageCollection: modLSTc,
  region: chakwal,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  scale: 1000,
  xProperty: 'system:time_start'})
  .setOptions({
     title: 'LST 2012 Time Series',
     vAxis: {title: 'LST Celsius'}});

print(ts1);

var clippedLSTc = modLSTc.mean().clip(chakwal);

Map.addLayer(clippedLSTc, {
  min: 23, max: 34,
  palette: ['blue', 'limegreen', 'yellow', 'darkorange', 'red']},
  'Mean temperature, 2012');

Export.image.toDrive({
  image: clippedLSTc,
  description: 'LST_Celsius_ug',
  folder: 'my_folder',
  region:chakwal,
  scale: 1000,
  crs: 'EPSG:4326',
  maxPixels: 1e10}
);
```

When you run [above code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/5f4e7d740263bddea576b8f9b7d496bb) in GEE code editor, result is as follows. Now, it is only considered **Chakwal** district instead complete Pakistan.

[image]